# Multi-dimensional indexing of 4d numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array, indexing, indices, numpy-ndarray

I have two 3d volumes stacked in a 4d array with dimensions 2x5x5x5.

If I want to get the values of some/all voxel for a single 3d volume, I can use three vectors and get the following:

```
x_new_mesh, y_new_mesh, z_new_mesh = np.meshgrid(np.arange(m),
                                                 np.arange(n),
                                                 np.arange(p))

x_new = x_new_mesh.flatten()
y_new = y_new_mesh.flatten()
z_new = z_new_mesh.flatten()
values = vol[x_new, y_new, z_new]
```

With m,n,p = 5 and x, y, z being 1x125 vectors. I get a 1x125 array back and no issues.

However, I haven't managed to do a similar thing with my stacked volumes. How can I use two sets of indices (different indices for each volume) to obtain a 2x125 array with the desired values?

Comment: oops, edited it!

Answer (score 0):

assuming vol is your 2x5x5x5 array:

```
values = vol[:, x_new, y_new, z_new]
```

Comment: thanks for replying! However, x_new, y_new, and z_new are not the same for both volumes. If I do this with them being 2x125, I get a 2x2x125 array, with repeated values. I can then delete half of them, but I'm limited by RAM (the volumes I use are much larger, so having them doubled is a problem)

Comment: don't make them 2x125. My answer assumed that you defined them the same way that you did in your example (that is, each of them is shape (125,)).